# Cannot install dictionaries-common package due to error running postins script

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I run: `sudo apt install -f`
After that this is my console output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up dictionaries-common (1.28.1) ...
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.28.1) ...
update-default-wordlist:
  Could not make the default symlink to "/usr/share/dict/american-english".
  This may be a temporary problem due to installation ordering. If that
  file is not present after installation, please file a bugreport
  against wordlist package owning that file.
  
dpkg: error processing package dictionaries-common (--configure):
 installed dictionaries-common package post-installation script subprocess retur
ned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dictionaries-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried ubuntu-bug but I got this error:

```
ERROR: symptom script /usr/share/apport/symptoms/installer.py crashed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/ui.py", line 95, in thread_collect_info
    package = symb['run'](report, ui)
  File "/usr/share/apport/symptoms/installer.py", line 9, in run
    with os.scandir('/var/log/installer') as entries:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/installer'
```

Comment: Did you read the console output? It suggests a test and a next step. Use `ubuntu-bug`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.